# mysql query INDEX is needed?

Tags: mysql, select, indexing, database-administration

I have a follow system in my website, it is an online game.
So, in this game, one player can follow the other one to make alliances.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `follow` (
  `player` INT NOT NULL REFERENCES cadastro (`id`),
  `follow` INT NOT NULL REFERENCES cadastro (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

`player` is who is following.
My question is, if, in the future this table contains a large number of users, should I use index? how can I use this?

what I do in my game is:

```
select `follow` from follow where player = $
```

so the index should be `player`? any optimization help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing `player` would definitely speed up your query if the table becomes large. If this is the only query you intend to run on the table, I'd index `player, follow`, so the query can be searched by `player`, and then the value of `follow` retrieved from the same index, without ever having to access the table for it.

Comment: just add this? INDEX player (`player`), INDEX follow (`follow`)

Comment: @RickJoe no, that would create two separate indexes. I'm suggesting to add `INDEX(player, follow)`. Or better yet - `PRIMARY KEY(player, follow)`.

Comment: on, nice! so if I use primary key (player, follow) I don't need to use INDEX?

Comment: @RickJoe no, you don't. A primary key (and a unique constraint too, btw), implicitly create the index.

Answer (score 0):

When representing a many-to-many relationship like this, best practice is usually to make your primary key a multikey on both `player` and `follow`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you probably need to go through this many-to-many mapping both ways, you need both:

```
PRIMARY KEY(player, follow),
INDEX      (follow, player)
```